# What happens if the Miller-Selfridge-Rabin-Test fails

Tags: public-key, prime-numbers

MRT is a probabilistic test and even the deterministic version relies on the correctness of the Riemann hypothesis.

When the test fails and I use a non-prime number in e.g a public key encryption method: what is going to happen? Will my public key not work, will it be a little less secure or will it be completely insecure, or something else?

BTW: how common is the use of the deterministic version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the test fails and I use a non-prime number in e.g a public key encryption method: what is going to happen?

It depends on what the non-prime number is used for, and on it's characteristics.

In [RSA](https://pkcs1.free.fr), any use of the key (for encryption/decryption, or signature/verification) constitutes a [Fermat test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test) for the would-be-prime factors $p$ and $q$ of the public modulus $n$. Therefore:

- If the non-prime number $p$ is a [Carmichael number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number), or becomes one¹ when multiplied by $q$ or some factor(s) thereof, and the formula $d=e^{-1}\bmod((p-1)(q-1))$ is used to compute the private exponent *or* [it's used $d=e^{-1}\bmod(\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1))$ and $q$ is prime], and $\gcd(p,q)=1$, then the key will work normally. However $n=p\,q$ will be easy to factor (relative to using a proper RSA modulus of comparable size), thus the cryptosystem relatively insecure. That's extremely unlikely to happen by chance, since Carmichael numbers are vanishingly rare.
- Otherwise, almost any use of the key will fail. In particular, if the key is submitted to a certification authority, the Certificate Signing Request will almost certainly fail to verify², thus the key won't be certified .

> How common is the use of the deterministic version?

When generating long-term parameters like Elliptic Curves, it's common to perform a deterministic primality test, such as Bernstein's [essentially quartic](http://cr.yp.to/primetests/quartic-20060914-ams.pdf) (in [Mathematics of Computation, 2007](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-44499-8_27)) variant of [AKS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/primality_journal.pdf) (in [Anals of Mathematics, 2004](https://doi.org/10.4007/annals.2004.160.781)). For individual (typically, RSA) keys, it's more common (because it's much faster) to generate a randomly-seeded provably prime integer. See e.g. [FIPS 186-4 appendix B.3.3](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22:138,%22gen%22:0%7D,%7B%22name%22:%22XYZ%22%7D,70,491,0%5D), or  Marc Joye, Pascal Paillier and Serge Vaudenay: [*Efficient Generation of Prime Numbers*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-44499-8_27.pdf), in [proceedings of CHES 2000](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-44499-8_27).

---

¹ I doubt this can happen if that other factor $q$ is prime and of the same size as the non-prime $p$. But it can happen if $q$ is composite too. Example:
$$\begin{align}
p&=(6\cdot84205+1)(36\cdot84205+1)=&1531547654011\\
q&=(12\cdot84205+1)(18\cdot84205+1)=&1531546643551\\
n&=p\,q=&2345636668938955292433061\\
e&=&65537\\
d&=e^{-1}\bmod((p-1)(q-1))=&748712536086026655061973
\end{align}$$
form a working RSA key! With $d=e^{-1}\bmod(\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1))=1170861048741587873$, that's no longer the case.

² Recall that a CSR is is signed with the private key which public key is to be certified, and verified against that public key by the certification authority.

Comment: Great! So, in the case if Carmichael numbers it’s simply bad luck? One thing I don’t understand is how certification authorities can tell that the key doesn’t work. Wouldn’t „Not working normally“ establish a deterministic test? Or *is* it the deterministic test that is used?

Comment: In partly retract my comment. It’s the Fermat test! But that leaves a very small chance that both Miller-Rabin *and* Fermat test fail, doesn’t it?

Comment: @Hartmut Braun: yes. But there a plausible cause to a composite passing the MSR test: an error in the implementation of the MSR test; and except a Carmichael number I don't see any plausible cause to a successful signature verification in RSA with one of the factor composite.

Comment: Actually, it's possible to come up with an RSA product involving a noncarmichael composite that actually works (!).  For example, consider $p=703 = 19 \times 37$ and $q = 17$; obviously, $p$ is composite and not a Carmichael number, however computing $e, d$ using $\text{lcm}( p-1, q-1 )$ works; for example, $e=5, d=4493$.  From the 'obscure facts about RSA department..."